# login page need to redirect to the another page in play 2 framework using scala

Tags: scala, playframework

i'm new to play 2,when I tried to create the cRUD application when I submit the details its redirect to the same page but I want to do in separate page 
and i enclosure with my controller and models and also views in below

```
  package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Contact
import play.api.Play.current

import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.Play.current
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
import views._
class  Contacts @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {


  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(Contact.all, Contact.form))
  }


  def create = Action { implicit request =>
    Contact.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Contact.all, errors)),
      contact => {
        Contact.create(contact)
        Redirect(routes.Contacts.index())
      }
    )
  }

  def edit(id: Long) = Action {
    Contact.get(id).map { contact =>
      Ok(views.html.edit(id, Contact.form.fill(contact)))
    } getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Contacts.index())
    }
  }


  def update(id: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    Contact.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.edit(id, errors)),
      contact => {
        Contact.update(id, contact)
        Redirect(routes.Contacts.index())
      }
    )
  }


  def delete(id: Long) = Action {
    Contact.delete(id)
    Redirect(routes.Contacts.index())
  }
}
```

and my model class:

```
package models

import java.lang

import anorm._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._

case class Contact(id: Long, name: String, emailAddress: String,age:Int,phone:Int)

object Contact {

  def all = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val contacts = SQL("SELECT * FROM contacts")().map { row =>
        Contact(
          id = row[Long]("id"),
          name = row[String]("name"),
          emailAddress = row[String]("emailAddress"),
          phone=row[Int]("phone"),
          age=row[Int]("age")
        )
      }

      contacts.toList
    }
  }

  def create(contact: Contact) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("INSERT INTO contacts(name, emailAddress ,phone , age) VALUES({name},{emailAddress},{phone},{age})").on(
        "name" -> contact.name,
        "emailAddress" -> contact.emailAddress,
        "phone"->contact.phone,
        "age"->contact.age
      ).execute()
    }
  }

  def get(id: Long) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> id)().headOption.map { row =>
        Contact(
          id = row[Long]("id"),
          name = row[String]("name"),
          emailAddress = row[String]("emailAddress"),
            phone=row[Int]("phone"),
          age=row[Int]("age")
        )
      }
    }
  }

  def show(contact: Contact) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("UPDATE contacts SET name={name}, emailAddress={emailAddress},phone={phone},age={age} WHERE id={id}").on(
        "name" -> contact.name,
        "emailAddress" -> contact.emailAddress,
        "phone"->contact.phone,
        "age"->contact.age
      ).execute()
    }
  }

  def update(id: Long, contact: Contact) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("UPDATE contacts SET name={name}, emailAddress={emailAddress},phone={phone},age={age} WHERE id={id}").on(
         "id" -> id,
        "name" -> contact.name,
        "emailAddress" -> contact.emailAddress,
         "phone"->contact.phone,
         "age"->contact.age
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }


  def delete(id: Long) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> id).execute()
    }
  }

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> ignored(0L),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "emailAddress" -> email,
      "phone"->number,
      "age"->number
    )(Contact.apply)(Contact.unapply)
  )

}
```

and my views

```
@(id: Long,contacts: List[models.Contact], form: Form[models.Contact],contact:Form[models.Contact])(implicit messages: Messages)
@layout {

  <h2>Update Contact</h2>

  @helper.form(action = routes.Contacts.update(id)) {

    @helper.inputText(contact("name"), '_label -> "Name")
    @helper.inputText(contact("phone"), '_label -> "phone")
    @helper.inputText(contact("age"), '_label -> "age")
    @helper.inputText(contact("emailAddress"), '_label -> "Email Address")


    <input type="submit" value="Update Contact" />

    <div style="width: 100%;
      background-color: #4a37ad">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>age</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for(contact <- contacts) {
          <tr>
            <td>@contact.name</td>
            <td>@contact.emailAddress</td>
            <td>@contact.phone</td>
            <td>@contact.age</td>
            <td>
              <a href='@routes.Contacts.edit(contact.id)'>Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            @helper.form(action = routes.Contacts.delete(contact.id)) {
              <input type="submit" value="Delete!" />
            }
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: To which page do you want to redirect? Not sure if I get your question.

Comment: when i press the submit all the details are stored and its shows the details at the same page but i want to implement on different page i ain't know how to done

Comment: `Redirect(routes.Contacts.index())` You just need to point this to a different view -> Implement a new view and create a controller method that calls this view instead of the index view. Or am I missing something?

Comment: how could i do that? can u edit the above the code and do it..beacz i'm told confusing

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new view. Something along the lines (let's call it `contact.view.html`):

```
@(contact: models.Contact)
@layout {

  <h2>Your new Contact</h2>
    <div style="width: 100%;
      background-color: #4a37ad">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>@contact.name</td>
            <td>@contact.emailAddress</td>
            <td>@contact.phone</td>
            <td>@contact.age</td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
}
```

Then you need to use this view in your controller method (e.g. `create`):

```
def create = Action { implicit request =>
    Contact.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Contact.all, errors)),
      contact => {
        Contact.create(contact)
        Redirect(views.html.contact(contact))
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: @arvindaudacious Can you be a bit more specific? Where is the error? I didn't test this, since I don't have your code. I made a change to the view, to point to `models.Contact` instead of just `Contact`.

Comment: Hi  ,thwiegan where was the for loop becaz it only returns my list data and i need to show the every list of data the above code shows only one

Comment: @arvindaudacious  Well then put the loop back. I don't know what you want to display on that other page. You just told me that you want to redirect to another page, which I demonstrated.

Comment: Ok thwiegan thanks for ur help and cooperation really helpful